Extending a git project: is fork the best option?
I've seen some similar questions on here, but not quite this one, and this question is mostly a sanity check:
Let's say I have a git project called "MyLibrary". I want to add functionality to it for two different platforms, "Platform1" and "Platform2", and I don't want Platform1 code in the Platform2 version of the library, and vice versa. If there is new functionality that will be useful to both platforms, I want to add it to the core MyLibrary, and then propagate it to both platform versions.
I think the best solution for this is to fork MyLibrary into two additional projects; "MyLibrary-Platform1" and "MyLibrary-Platform2" (don't worry about naming conventions, this is just for example), and then when I make changes to MyLibrary that I want in both versions, I can use Github to sync those forked projects to the core MyLibrary.
The second best solution would be to have a "Platform1" branch and "Platform2" branch of "MyLibrary" in the same project. But I think that would get messy with the platform branches using the same system as PR branches, and it runs the risk of accidentally merging a PR that's supposed to go into a platform branch into main.
Am I correct in thinking that the forking method is the best solution, or is there something else that would be better?

Your approach is good but if you have core functionalities to be shared on Project 1 and Project 2, you can do git submodules.
In that the particular core app is on its own repository then add it as a git submodule on the main project, I hope this helps.

testing that, it looks like changes to files within the submodule cannot be committed to the platform project, and cause errors when trying to update the submodule. I realize it's generally bad form, but I need to be able to make per-platform changes to some of the individual core files.
